# How to trigger Jenkins build on specific branch(release branch) merges to master in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, git-merge

I am trying to trigger a build on the master branch when a specific branch is merged into it i.e., To trigger a Jenkins pipeline build when a release branch is merged to the master branch.

What I am able to do is if any branch is merged to master, it is triggering the Jenkins build, but what I want is to build to be only triggered on release branch merges into master. For this I used Generic webhook trigger Plugin(GWT). Not sure if I can use Generic webhook trigger for specific branch merge into master.

I tried the following settings in Jenkins pipeline configuration using GWT plugin.
Optional Filter:
Expression -  `^(refs/heads/master)$`
This expression is working when I merge any branch into Master and triggering the build. But, I want the merge to happen just when a release branch is merged into Master.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the

```
when
```

step in your pipeline. There you use the environment variable which contains you branch name from the generic webhook trigger plugin.